# return new instance of current class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

i'd like to return a new instance of the current class, when an inherited class return it will return the base class instead of the current class

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1
        self.bar = 2
    def new(self):
        return class1()

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

c1 = class1()
c2 = class2()
print(c1.new())
print(c2.new())
```

this returns

<**main**.class1 object at 0x0000027B681E57F0>
<**main**.class1 object at 0x0000027B681E57F0>

desired result

<**main**.class1 object at 0x0000027B681E57F0>
<**main**.class2 object at 0x0000027B681E57F0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current class like this:

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1
        self.bar = 2
    def new(self):
        return self.__class__()
```

Inheritors will return their own classes.  You will have to handle the logic for any different `__init__` signatures yourself, however.   A classmethod would be a better design choice unless you needed information from the current instance to create the new one.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) for that:

```
class class1(object):
    def new(self):
        return self.__class__()

class class2(class1):
    pass

c1 = class1()
c2 = class2()
print(c1.new())
print(c2.new())
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a class method instead:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1
        self.foo = 2

    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        return cls()

class Class2(Class1):
    pass
```

Now when you call `c2.new()`, the runtime will see that `Class2` has no method named `new`, but `Class1` does. Further, `Class2` will be passed as the implicit argument to `new`, not `Class1`.

The class method is more appropriate than an instance method because you don't have any other interest in the object invoking the method beyond what class it is.